# If statement for jframe main method doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, static, non-static

I'm new to java, 
I'm trying to select shape using jframe and then display the area using console output, I tried using as below but it's giving me an error. Not sure how to do an if statement. 
Thank you in advance

```
package shapes;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class design extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int type;
    int xtl, ytl, xtr, ytr, xbl, ybl,xbr, ybr;
    /**
     * Creates new form design
     */
    public design() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Quadrilateral");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Rectangle");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Parallelogram");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Square");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Trapezoid");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("X:");

        jLabel2.setText("Y:");

        jLabel3.setText("Top left point");

        jLabel4.setText("Top right point");

        jLabel5.setText("Bottom left point");

        jLabel6.setText("Bottom right point");

        jTextField1.setText("               ");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setText("               ");
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.setText("               ");
        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField4.setText("               ");
        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField5.setText("              ");
        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField6.setText("               ");
        jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField7.setText("               ");
        jTextField7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField8.setText("               ");
        jTextField8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                                .addComponent(jButton4)
                                .addGap(142, 142, 142)
                                .addComponent(jButton5)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField5))
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)))
                                .addGap(137, 137, 137))))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(75, 75, 75))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            ybl = Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText());    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            type =1;
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            type =2;
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            type =3;

    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            type =4;
            // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            type =5;
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            xtl = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

    }                                           

    private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            ytl = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());

    }                                           

    private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            xtr = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
    }                                           

    private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            ytr = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
    }                                           

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            xbl = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            xbr = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    }                                           

    private void jTextField8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            ybr = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());                                               
    }                                           
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {


      //it is giving me an error here! /////////////////////////////////////////
        if (type==1){
       System.out.println("Text1");
        }
       if (type==2){
       System.out.println("Text2");
        }
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(design.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(design.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(design.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(design.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                new design().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please for this type of question **always** post the complete error message as well as indicate which line causes it. This is just common sense.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable type cannot be referenced from a static context
 at shapes.design.main(design.java:316)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Firstly never try to run code that doesn't compile. Next, check the link to the duplicate question.

Comment: I did but I didn't understand, the question is higher level for me. Would you please explain to me what is wrong with my if statement at the end of the code. Thanks

Comment: You need to study your textbook or a introductory tutorial and understand the meaning of static and instance, it's as simple as that.

Comment: Also, have a look at the search capabilities of this site by clicking on this [link to similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+non-static+variable+referenced). Many of these questions will explain the problem, and hopefully you can find some that will be easily understandable for you.